# What is happening inside a linear medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I am very new to optics and am trying to understand the meaning of linear and non-linear terms.

To be more specific I am trying to understand second-harmonic generation as explained [in this video](https://youtu.be/3WevI1A2Bdk?list=PLq-Gm0yRYwTgs2qOLnHChlKr3tk01gW33&t=619).

First thing first let us start with the basics. Assuming we have a linear medium then to my understanding the relevant term is

$$\mathrm{P}_{\mathrm{L}} =  \epsilon_0 \chi^{(1)} \mathrm{E}$$

where $\mathrm{P}_{\mathrm{L}}$ is the polarization **of the medium** (if I understood that correctly). $ \mathrm{E}$ on the other hand is the electric field of the Laser that goes into the medium? Or is $ \mathrm{E}$ the field generated inside the medium ?

Any help is welcome (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this equation E is the external field.

By the way, don't study physics from a video. Use a textbook, for example Jackson or http://optics.byu.edu/textbook.aspx. Or take a course.